# How can I convert a DataTable into a Dynamic object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, datatable, ienumerable

How can I convert a `DataTable` in `IEnumerable<dynamicObject>`?

For example, I want to convert *any* `DataTable`

```
ID | Name          DI | emaN
---------    or    ---------
 1 | x              2 | x
 2 | y              1 | y
```

In a list of objects

```
// list 1      (ex 1)             // list 2    (ex 2)
{                                 {
  { ID = 1, Name = "x" }            { DI = 2, emaN = "x" }
  { ID = 2, Name = "y" }            { DI = 1, emaN = "y" }
}                                 }
```

So

```
list1.First().ID    // 1
list2.First().emaN  // "x"
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about with [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx):

```
public static class DataTableX
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> AsDynamicEnumerable(this DataTable table)
    {
        // Validate argument here..

        return table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new DynamicRow(row));
    }

    private sealed class DynamicRow : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly DataRow _row;

        internal DynamicRow(DataRow row) { _row = row; }

        // Interprets a member-access as an indexer-access on the 
        // contained DataRow.
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            var retVal = _row.Table.Columns.Contains(binder.Name);
            result = retVal ? _row[binder.Name] : null;
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also try overriding `TrySetMember` if you wish to make the dynamic-row writable.

**Usage**:

```
  DataTable table = ...
  var dynamicTable = table.AsDynamicEnumerable();

  var firstRowsNameField = dynamicTable.First().Name;
```

Answer (score 47):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "x");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "y");

        List<dynamic> dynamicDt = dt.ToDynamic();
        Console.WriteLine(dynamicDt.First().ID);
        Console.WriteLine(dynamicDt.First().Name);
    }
}

public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamic(this DataTable dt)
    {
        var dynamicDt = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
            dynamicDt.Add(dyn);
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
                dic[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
            }
        }
        return dynamicDt;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a little big mistake man! The line
`dynamicDt.Add(dyn);`
Should be outside the inner loop.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me as I just want to bind to datagrid from datatable.

Comment: To my .NET Core project I had to add the NuGet Microsoft.CSharp.

Comment: Why all the casting?
            List<dynamic> dataDyn = new List<dynamic>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();                
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)                
                    dic.Add(column.ColumnName, row[column]);                
                dataDyn.Add(dic);
            }

Answer (score 6):

Previous suneelsarraf codes only generated runtime dynamic object with property as string.
following update will generate each property based on DataTable column's data type.

```
public static class DataTableExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Convert a database data table to a runtime dynamic definied type collection (dynamic class' name as table name).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt"></param>
    /// <param name="className"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamicList(DataTable dt, string className)
    {
        return ToDynamicList(ToDictionary(dt), getNewObject(dt.Columns, className));
    }

    private static List<Dictionary<string, object>> ToDictionary(DataTable dt)
    {
        var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
        var Temp = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => columns.Select(column =>
                             new { Column = column.ColumnName, Value = dataRow[column] })
                         .ToDictionary(data => data.Column, data => data.Value)).ToList();
        return Temp.ToList();
    }

    private static List<dynamic> ToDynamicList(List<Dictionary<string, object>> list, Type TypeObj)
    {
        dynamic temp = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> step in list)
        {
            object Obj = Activator.CreateInstance(TypeObj);

            PropertyInfo[] properties = Obj.GetType().GetProperties();

            Dictionary<string, object> DictList = (Dictionary<string, object>)step;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in DictList)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    if (property.Name == keyValuePair.Key)
                    {
                        if (keyValuePair.Value != null && keyValuePair.Value.GetType() != typeof(System.DBNull))
                        {
                            if (keyValuePair.Value.GetType() == typeof(System.Guid))
                            {
                                property.SetValue(Obj, keyValuePair.Value, null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                property.SetValue(Obj, keyValuePair.Value, null);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            temp.Add(Obj);
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private static Type getNewObject(DataColumnCollection columns, string className)
    {
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
        assemblyName.Name = "YourAssembly";
        System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("YourDynamicModule");
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = module.DefineType(className, TypeAttributes.Public);

        foreach (DataColumn column in columns)
        {
            string propertyName = column.ColumnName;
            FieldBuilder field = typeBuilder.DefineField(propertyName, column.DataType, FieldAttributes.Public);
            PropertyBuilder property = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.None, column.DataType, new Type[] { column.DataType });
            MethodAttributes GetSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
            MethodBuilder currGetPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_value", GetSetAttr, column.DataType, new Type[] { column.DataType }); // Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator currGetIL = currGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            MethodBuilder currSetPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_value", GetSetAttr, null, new Type[] { column.DataType });
            ILGenerator currSetIL = currSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            property.SetGetMethod(currGetPropMthdBldr);
            property.SetSetMethod(currSetPropMthdBldr);
        }
        Type obj = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        return obj;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some ORMs that can read directly from DB to `dynamic ExpandoObject`. For example [petapoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) (and read here the [example](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/104/PetaPoco-Not-So-Poco-or-adding-support-for-dynamic))

Or you could try something similar:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

var dns = new List<dynamic>();

foreach (var item in dt.AsEnumerable())
{
    // Expando objects are IDictionary<string, object>
    IDictionary<string, object> dn = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var column in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
    {
        dn[column.ColumnName] = item[column];
    }

    dns.Add(dn);
}

// Now you can do something like dns[0].MyColumnName 
// or recast to IDictionary<string, object> and do 
// something like casted["MyColumnName"]
```

Comment: you can't apply indexing with [] to an ExpandoObject, replace code with one existing here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794962/84216

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extension like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Dynamic;

public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> AsDynamicEnumerable(this DataTable table)
    {
        if (table == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> dRow = new ExpandoObject();

            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                var value = row[column.ColumnName];
                dRow[column.ColumnName] = Convert.IsDBNull(value) ? null : value;
            }

            yield return dRow;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var dataTable = GetDataTableFromSomewhere();
var dynamicTable = dataTable.AsDynamicEnumerable();
var firstRowIDColumn = dynamicTable.First().ID;
var lastRowIDColumn = dynamicTable.Last()["ID"];
```

But I prefered an IDataReader approach if possible.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var MyResult = from x in MyDataTable select new { ID = x["ID"], Name = x["Name"] }.ToList ();
```

Comment: I am thinking in something more generic.

Comment: you mean - without knowledge of the fields ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. New fields can appear or disappear, or it might be completely different fields.....

Comment: then your best option is to use some ORM like petapoco or Dapper - see the answer from xanatos

Answer (score 1):

Convert Datatable To List

```
    #region "Convert DataTable to List<dynamic>"

    public List<dynamic> ToDynamicList(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<string> cols = (dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()).Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToList();
        return ToDynamicList(ToDictionary(dt), getNewObject(cols));
    }
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> ToDictionary(DataTable dt)
    {
        var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
        var Temp = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => columns.Select(column =>
                             new { Column = column.ColumnName, Value = dataRow[column] })
                         .ToDictionary(data => data.Column, data => data.Value)).ToList();
        return Temp.ToList();
    }
    public List<dynamic> ToDynamicList(List<Dictionary<string, object>> list, Type TypeObj)
    {
        dynamic temp = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> step in list)
        {
            object Obj = Activator.CreateInstance(TypeObj);
            PropertyInfo[] properties = Obj.GetType().GetProperties();
            Dictionary<string, object> DictList = (Dictionary<string, object>)step;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in DictList)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    if (property.Name == keyValuePair.Key)
                    {
                        property.SetValue(Obj, keyValuePair.Value.ToString(), null);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            temp.Add(Obj);
        }
        return temp;
    }       
    private Type getNewObject(List<string> list)
    {
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
        assemblyName.Name = "tmpAssembly";
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("tmpModule");
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = module.DefineType("WebgridRowCellCollection", TypeAttributes.Public);
        foreach (string step in list)
        {
            string propertyName = step;
            FieldBuilder field = typeBuilder.DefineField(propertyName, typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public);
            PropertyBuilder property = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(string), new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            MethodAttributes GetSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
            MethodBuilder currGetPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_value", GetSetAttr, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator currGetIL = currGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            MethodBuilder currSetPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_value", GetSetAttr, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            ILGenerator currSetIL = currSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
            currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            property.SetGetMethod(currGetPropMthdBldr);
            property.SetSetMethod(currSetPropMthdBldr);
        }
        Type obj = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        return obj;
    }

    #endregion
```