# Convert DataTable to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, datatable, ado.net

I've reviewed the answers here:

- [How do you convert a DataTable into a generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list)
- [Convert DataTable to Generic List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104464/convert-datatable-to-generic-list-in-c-sharp)
  and
- [Fastest way to convert datatable to generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441023/fastest-way-to-convert-datatable-to-generic-list)

But they don't help for my particular use case.  I am retrieving a DataTable from a SQL data adapter and want to convert the DataTable into a List (that's easy enough) and then serialize the List into JSON (using JSON.net, that's easy enough).

The problem is that I seem to have to use List.  Ok, fine - so I have this code:

```
DataTable result = GoMagicallyGatherSomeData();
List<DataRow> ret = new List<DataRow>();
if (result != null && result.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (DataRow curr in result.Rows)
  {
    ret.Add(curr);
  }
}
```

or

```
DataTable result = GoMagicallyGatherSomeData();
List<DataRow> ret = result.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

When I go to serialize the List, it...  isn't what I expect.

What I would like to get back is:

```
[  
   {  
      "TestId":1,
      "AccountId":1,
      "SomeString":"This is an updated test",
      "SomeTimestamp":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "SomeDecimal":5.55
   },
   {  
      "TestId":3,
      "AccountId":1,
      "SomeString":"This is a third test",
      "SomeTimestamp":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "SomeDecimal":5.55
   },
   { ... removed for brevity ... }
]
```

And what I actually get back is:

```
[  
   {  
      "RowError":"",
      "RowState":2,
      "Table":[  
         {  
            "TestId":1,
            "AccountId":1,
            "SomeString":"This is an updated test",
            "SomeTimestamp":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "SomeDecimal":5.55
         },
         {  
            "TestId":3,
            "AccountId":1,
            "SomeString":"This is a second test",
            "SomeTimestamp":"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "SomeDecimal":5.55
         }, 
         { ... removed for brevity ... }
      ],
      "ItemArray":[  
         1,
         1,
         "This is an updated test",
         "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
         5.55
      ],
      "HasErrors":false
   },
   {  
      "RowError":"",
      "RowState":2,
      "Table":[  

      ... there seems to be an instance of this for every row in the result ...

      ],
      "ItemArray":[  
         1,
         1,
         "This is an updated test",
         "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
         5.55
      ],
      "HasErrors":false
   }
]
```

The other challenge is that I need to do this without awareness of the actual type of the data.

Any insight?  Anyone have a suggestion on the best way to do this?  Could I get away with copying out the 'table' array from the first serialized DataRow, or, could subsequent serialized DataRows actually contain different data than the first?

Comment: You need a DTO to generate the JSON you're after.

Comment: Why the downvote please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could convert the `DataTable` into a `List<dynamic>` and then convert it to json. For sample, to convert to a dynamic list:

```
public static List<dynamic> ConvertToDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
{
    var result = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();      
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
            dic[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
        }
        result.Add(dyn);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You also could make an extension method like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794962/316799). Then use it and to convert to `List<dynamic>` and finally convert the list to json using the `JsonConvert` from [`Newtonsoft.Json (a.k.a. Json.Net)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). For sample:

```
var list = ConvertToDataTable(dataTable);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Comment: You are my hero.  This is exactly what I needed.  Perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: Neat solution as it implicitly consider a `DataRow` as `IDictionary<string,object>`, which helps in effective Json Serialization