# Convert DataTable into list when no of column is dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable in which no of columns is dynamic. I need a list with header name and value.I found a question similar to this question.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794818/how-can-i-convert-a-datatable-into-a-dynamic-object)

But can not getting desired output.
Output with this solution 
In Dynamic View :

[image]

In Result View
[image]

I m using this Code for Convert to dynamic object :

```
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamic(this DataTable dt)
    {
        var dynamicDt = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
                dic[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
            }
            dynamicDt.Add(dyn);
        }
        return dynamicDt;
    }
```

Need a output like that :-

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by modifying [the ToDynamic method you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794962/4574). The original method is:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static List<dynamic> ToDynamic(this DataTable dt)
    {
        var dynamicDt = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
            dynamicDt.Add(dyn);
            //--------- change from here
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
                dic[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
            }
            //--------- change up to here
        }
        return dynamicDt;
    }
}
```

Replace the lines between the "change" comments into:

```
foreach (var columnName in new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"} )
{
    var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
    if(dt.Columns.Contains(columnName))
        dic[columnName] = row[dt.Columns[columnName]];
    else
        dic[columnName] = 0;
}
```

That's assuming you need column names A to E, adjust as appropriate if you need more columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but here i m getting list of "{System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject}" but i need a list of all header name with values just like my output image and i don't want to filter on column names, because column name is dynamic

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "here"?

Comment: By using ToDynamic function

Comment: That's weird, might it be related to your debugging environment? You were using that `ToDynamic` in the first place, right?