# C# Template Engine which supports iterating through data rows in DataTable

Tags: c#, razorengine, stringtemplate, dotliquid, scriban

I'm looking for a C# template engine which supports iterating through data rows in DataTable. Something like,

```
var template = Template.Parse(@"
    <ul id='products'>
      {{ for dr in ds.tables[0].rows }}
         <li>
           <h2>{{ dr[0] }}</h2>
           Price: {{ dr[1] }}
         </li>
      {{ end }}
    </ul>
");

var result = template.Render(new { Ds = ds});
```

I tried Scriban, but it throws error

```
Scriban.Syntax.ScriptRuntimeException: '<input>(3,31) : error : Expecting a list. 
Invalid value `System.Data.DataTableCollection/DataTableCollection` for the target `ds.tables` for the indexer: ds.tables[0]'
```

Is there a way to make it work in Scriban, or is there any other template engine which supports DataSet

Comment: Why don't you create a list from the rows and pass that into your template?

Comment: Thanks @bhmahler! I was having that as a last option. Not sure of the performance, want to see if there is any engine which supports it by default.

Comment: I don't know of any that have that level of support, but that does not mean one doesn't exist.  Personally, I would create an object for your type, then create a list of said object and use that with your template.

Comment: Thanks @bhmahler! As you suggested, for now I'm converting the datatable to object as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794818/how-can-i-convert-a-datatable-into-a-dynamic-object/7794962#7794962)